# cannot install cordova-res (windows 10)

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I want to install cordova-res but it wont install.
I have tried many codes,

```
npm i -g cordova-res
npm i -g ionic cordova-res
```

Still not working.

Then I delete the node-modules >> remove android >> do 'npm i -g cordova-res', not working

Then I delete the node-modules >> npm install >> do 'npm i -g cordova-res', not working

How can I install the cordova-res?
Here is my ionic info

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

NodeJS : v8.9.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.12.1
   OS     : Windows 10

Here the error that I get

```html
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp 
(node "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else 
(node "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:282:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:294:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:196:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\40450\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for cordova-res@0.9.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.3.0"} (current: {"node":"8.9.4","npm":"6.12.1"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: cordova-res@0.9.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sharp@0.24.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.13.0"} (current: {"node":"8.9.4","npm":"6.12.1"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: sharp@0.24.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.1.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.9.4","npm":"6.12.1"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.1.2

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.24.0 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.24.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\40450\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-07T00_57_49_685Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is the exact error log that you are getting?

Comment: Sory, now I include my error in question..

Comment: It is clear from your error log that some of the node modules are relying on python. So install python again and make sure it is added in Environment path variable.

Comment: already install the python, and add in environment path variable.. then I test in command 'py'. The path is working but i still cannot install cordova-res.. and get the same error